# ListSurfacePlot3d

Tags: plotting

I am trying to plot a surface plot, but the surface plot is empty. It does show the frame of the plot if I plot with ListPointPlot3D, but not with ListSurfacePlot3D.

How can I make this data into a surface plot?

```
v = Table[Table[{xgrid[[i]], xgrid[[j]], u[[i*j]]}, {i, 1,Length[xgrid]}], {j, 1, Length[xgrid]}];

ListPointPlot3D[v, ViewPoint -> {0, -2, 0}] /. Point -> Line
ListSurfacePlot3D[v, PlotRange -> All]
ListPlot3D[v, Mesh -> All]
```

Here is ListPointPlot3D:
[image: ListPointPlot3D]

Here is ListSurfacePlot3D:
[image: ListSurfacePlot3D]

Comment: Try `ListSurfacePlot3D[ Flatten[v, 1] ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure of your table is wrong. Look at the nesting of the lists. 
For [`ListPlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot3D.html) or [`ListSurfacePlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListSurfacePlot3D.html), you need `v` to be of the form `{{x1,y1,z1},{x2,y2,z2},...}`.

Try

```
v2=Partition[Flatten[v],3]
```

and then do `ListPlot3D` or `ListSurfacePlot3D` on `v2`.

Comment: Or just `Flatten[v, 1]`

Comment: Thanks! I should have looked!